# Missing css from source code magento 2.4.2

Tags: magento2, css, magento2.4, missing

When upgrading to Magento 2.4.2 all of the core css is missing front both the back and frontends.

Looking at the source I see no reference to such lines such as

```
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="https://www.example.test/static/version1624020941/frontend/vendor/theme/en_GB/css/styles-m.css" />
```

Also stuff like the fav icon is not loading and reverting back to the Magento default

Anyone one got any advice

Comment: Please confirm your root path is pub directory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What is the exact version of PHP you are using?

If you use php 7.4.20

Edit that php.ini file and find the section `[Pcre]` and add this line at the bottom of that section :

```
pcre.jit=0
```

Restart your PHP

see : [Magento doesn't include theme.css in html](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/339914/magento-doesnt-include-theme-css-in-html)

Comment: Dude if I can buy you a beer you just let me know how!!! I've spent the best part of 20 hours debugging this thinking it was something I had done! Lifesaver

Comment: What @Goose84 said! I've been trying to resolve this for over a month now. Thank you so much!

Comment: I had this same problem. This fixed it right up. Amazing. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks You very much

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to remove that version from css path this can be done either form admin or we have to run one db query.

From Admin you can disable it from

```
Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Sign Static Files
```

from database you can hit below query in "core_config_data"

```
insert into core_config_data (config_id, scope, scope_id, path, value) values (null, 'default', 0, 'dev/static/sign', 0);
```

For more information please check [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/162205/magento-2-issue-with-getting-version-number-in-file-paths) link.

After these above changes run static content deploy command:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try these two solutions, it might help you

**Solution 1:**

in `app/etc/di.xml` find the virtualType `name="developerMaterialization"` section. In that section you'll find an item `name="view_preprocessed"` that needs to be modified or deleted. You can modify it by changing the contents

From `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink`
To `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy`

Delete the files under pub/static to get rid of any existing symlinks.
**Note: You may want to be careful not to delete the .htaccess file.**

run deployment script and check if your issue is resolved.

**Solution 2:**

override `vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/DriverInterface.php`

probably on line 20, change permission to **0755**
and probably on line 25, change permission to **644**

Hope one of the above solution resolve your issue.