# Magento 2.4.2 php7.4.2 assets not showing on frontend or admin panel

Tags: magento2

On a 2.4.2 install with php7.4.2 (apache) in developer mode both grunt and static-content:deploy -f compile assets, but they are not linked in the header of the site in either the admin panel or in the storefront.  This is occurring on multiple sites.  This is not a 404 error, the files simply do not show up in the header, so there is no network request being made.

- mod_rewrite is enabled,
- .htaccess files do exist in all appropriate directories
- permissions opened wide
- dev/sign/static = 0

I've tried this in production mode and still there are no assets.  On a whim I switched to php 7.3 and the assets actually compile on one site and were available on the front end.  Looking for any additional ideas on this one.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/340107/missing-css-from-source-code-magento-2-4-2

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much for this. I have searched for this answer all over and tried just about everything.  I wish they would have included that here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/php-settings.html